# currentUser data doesn't update after changes to it when opening/closing a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i have a user profile modal in my next app where its data and the user can change it by typing in inputs. The problem is that old data doesn't overwrites in modal when i open it or close but in my db it changes. I can get new data only after page refresh.

How i render it:

```
  <>
    {children}
    <LogOut />
    <Profile />
  </>
```

Hook:

```
export const useGetCurrentUser = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<CurrentUser | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid));
        setCurrentUser(snapshot.data() as CurrentUser);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return { currentUser, loading };
};
```

Modal:

```
export const Profile = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const profileModal = searchParams.get("profileModal");

  const { currentUser } = useGetCurrentUser(); // get data from a custom hook

  return (
   ...
  );
};
```

Comment: Without the code of the `useGetCurrentUser` hook it is basically impossible to answer your question. Please rephrase your question to include all necessary details, code and context for the community to provide an answer.

Comment: I suspect what is happening in your code is because the `useEffect` dependency array is empty so the code is only ever run once, hence the stale data received from your custom hook. But of course it can be that whatever `onAuthStateChanged` is, is only called once by the callee.

Comment: What would you suggest to do? I also have a navbar where I use this data, so with every its render it  fetch again. Probably the logic of opening a modal is a bit different